# Cross Domain File Upload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, jsonp

Here's my problem. I want to do some file uploading in a website to my own one. So I had the well known "Same Origin Policy" issue.
Another problem of mine is that I dont own the file uploader website and only can add html and js to an existing page. So I don't have the proxy alternative either.
So I had searched for some solution and found out that it's possible with XMLHTTPRequest. but I can't find out how. Also I'm wondering if JSONP may be my solution or not.
Any idea for a "Best Solution" will be appreciated.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a form containing a file input and set the action to the third party site.

This will be blocked if the third party site implements CSRF protection.

Since you have ruled out using a proxy, there is no way for you to determine the success or failure of the form submission.

---

> it's possible with XMLHTTPRequest

MDN have [a guide to uploading files with XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown) — but to get any feedback, this would require that the third party site allow you access via CORS. It would fail completely if there was CSRF protection.

---

JSONP won't help since:

- You can only make GET requests with it
- The third party site much provide a JSONP endpoint for you to access

Comment: I own the third party site. the uploading site is not mine. How about sending the file with base64 or sth to my endpoint?

Comment: The only benefit to using Base64 if that you could encode the data in a query string … which would hit the maximum supported URL length for non-tiny files.

Comment: That's right! about your first solution, can I do it using js and without page postback or not?

Comment: The second section of my answer covers that, not the first. (Since you control the target site, you can allow access via CORS and not implement CSRF protection)

Comment: could you do me a favor and put some js code to use XMLHttpRequest without page postback.

Comment: There is some at the other end of the link in the answer.

Comment: forgive me to be a newbie, but in that code, what's File, FormData and how should I get the filepath? Are those defined in standard JS or what?

Comment: Details of File and FormData are linked to in the two paragraphs preceding the code example. The file spec links to a [tutorial on using it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Comment: Thanks my friend. Finally I get it to work. But that's only compatible with IE10+ and I'm not sure to use it.